# Hibernate: check which entity's fields are modified

Tags: java, hibernate, design-patterns, jpa, architecture

***What I have:***

I've Hibernate entity, which contains many non-transient fields, including collections. User can update each field separately or some group of fields at once.

***What a challange:***

In handler I should check what field of the entity  have been changed:

```
public void handle(Entity newVersion) {
  Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
  Entity oldVersion = (Entity) session.get(Entity.class, entity.getId());
  List changedFields = compareChanges(oldVersion, newVersion);  //HOW TO CHECK WHICH FIELDS ARE CHANGED?
}
```

I want to do it for security and notification reasons. Means:

1. Not all users can modify all fields
2. I should notify specific users in specific ways on some fields change.

***What a problem:***

I get very ugly code. Actually I iterate throught all fields/collections and call `equals` method.

***Question:***

*May be Hibernate provide more elegant way to check what fields have been modified? How?*

***P.S.***

@victorantunes provide a solution, but it seems too comprehensive for me. May be some alternatives?

Comment: How about using the apache commons? check this link out. http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/builder/EqualsBuilder.html

Comment: @Khush if I understand you, I should check all entity's fields for equality and than manually call appropriate methods if they aren't equals. It isn't a thing I'm looking for.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

What you can do is make a Hibernate Interceptor that would act like a trigger in the events like create, modify and update.
http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/events.html
so that any point before the given entity is about to be modified and persisted, 
1.You can check whether the user has the access (you can get username from session or database) to modify the particular field and accordingly you can grant the access to save or update.
2.You can notify the other user about only when the entity is modified.

By this way you can make a new session-scope Interceptor in spring's implementation ofHibernate 4 
Session session = s.withOptions().interceptor(new YourInterceptor().openSession();

Comment: yes, @Bimalesh Jha already said about that. But again, I can't find the way to set session-scope interceptor: there is no `openSession` method which take an iterceptor as input parameter

Comment: There is generally two way to set interceptor,
1.Session scope
2.Session factory
So in your case , you can make the interceptor session-scoped while creating session object by,
Session session = s.openSession( new YourInterceptor() );

Comment: I use org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean for my sessionFactory. And my sessionFactory HAS ONLY ONE openSession() method WITHOUT ARGUMENTS (( How should I make my interceptor session-scoped?

Comment: It works well in hibernate 3.2.5
If not that then what you can do is you can make your own new DAO methods and save that entity through that DAO method.
In that DAO method what you can do is check the user and accordingly give the access to save or modify that entity

Comment: I haven't DAO layer in my application. Its a small app so I have no need to use it.

Comment: try this, hope it works for you
Session session = s.withOptions()
                    .interceptor(new YourInterceptor())
                    .openSession();

Comment: thanks, I can set interceptor in such way. I'll test if this solution in two days.

Answer (score 8):

If what you want is to be able to check which fields have been modified, it may be worth taking a look at Hibernate Envers, which works as an auditing tool that creates a separate table containing the changes that were made to your business logic table.

http://www.jboss.org/envers

I started using it for some internal auditing and it's really simple and works like a charm.

Here's a quick tutorial:

https://thenewcircle.com/s/post/115/easy_auditing_versioning_for_your_hibernate_entities_with_envers

Comment: Yes, thanks. But it only needed for two qute similar entites, not for all. May some approach that doesn't require additional libraries/tools?

Comment: Maybe I'm wrong, but with help of Envers it is possible to see changes after they are commited, but I want to check for changes before they are maded.

Comment: You could implement hibernate EmtyInterceptor and override   boolean onFlushDirty(
   Object entity, 
   Serializable id, 
   Object[] currentState, 
   Object[] previousState, 
   String[] propertyNames, 
   Type[] types) method

Answer (score 1):

I think Hibernate interceptors can be used  http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/events.html you can compare old and new values of the entity fields.

Comment: is it a good practice to use interceptors for notifications (send emails to clients). Why?

Comment: moreover, this events/interseptors shouldn't be applied to the whole entity layer, but to entity in specific handle method. Is it possible? (I need to do such things only in two places in my application)

Comment: I am using it in a commercial product, not for emailing, but computing some stats counters. Haven't faced any issue.

Comment: I use `org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean` for my sessionFactory. And my `sessionFactory` HAS ONLY ONE `openSession()` method WITHOUT ARGUMENTS (( How should I make my interceptor session-scoped?

Comment: @VolodymyrBakhmatiuk thinking more, even for emailing you can use the interceptors. Just introduce some kind of email queue. From interceptor you will determine the situation to send email and put the notification in the email queue. Another worker will take the email from queue and send notifications. This should work.