# List of dirty fields from managed entity

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

How can I get a list of dirty fields from managed entity? I know I can do such a thing when I use hibernate events

```
public boolean onFlushDirty(Object entity,
                            Serializable id,
                            Object[] currentState,
                            Object[] previousState,
                            String[] propertyNames,
                            Type[] types)
```

but I would like to get this without any special persistence operation on my entity. Comparing  field by field with original object is also bad idea.

Comment: Check this link! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19656882/hibernate-check-which-entitys-fields-are-modified

Comment: @conFusl I have checked but nothing found. Users advised to use events which require a persistence operation to be executed but this is a kind of bad design in my opinion. I am looking for something more elegant.
The second solution was to use envers which gives a big overhead in comparison to what I want to achieve.

Comment: Anyway thank you for your answer I hadn't known about session scope events before :)

Comment: but what's so bad about an interceptor who checks/control the lifecycle  and state? You're welcome! ;-)

Comment: please correct me if I am wrong. When you are creating an interceptor then it will be applied to all of the persistence operations for all of the entities not only for a single entity that I want. The second thing, I have to do a persistence operation to invoke one of my interceptors method (e.g. flush). I do not want to. It will be better if my code is transparent.